# Is it possible to check for specific text to highlight on AEM site without using JavaScript?

Tags: aem

Currently, I am building a feature in which author can decide which text to highlight throughout every single page of the site. In addition, when you hover over the highlighted text, the tooltip of the highlighted text will show the text's definition.

My idea is that the author will be given a component on a page. When the user open the component dialog, it will be given a multi-field to enter "text" and "definition" as a key-value pair. Since this data is not private, so I will render the data on a page, and use JavaScript to read data from the page and store in a dictionary.  Each time you load a page, JavaScript will check for the text in dictionary and do the trick.

I am not sure if my idea is a good idea. I am concerned that the site will be very slow on mobile if I do it in JavaScript. Is there a better approach to do the trick in Java model or anywhere on server side?

Comment: Why don't you do it at render time? Every change in the key-value list needs to be published anyway (which will flush your cache), so there is only static content that can and should be cached.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What can I do at render time?